# ckeditor - how to get custom-css with id to work?

Tags: css, ckeditor

Silly it seems, but can't get this to work:

```
css (custom.css):
====
#thePage h2 {color:#f00;}
```

.

```
the ck-config, in container-html:
=================================
...
//<![CDATA[
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
  bodyId : 'thePage',
  contentsCss : 'custom.css',
  ...
```

If **#thePage** is removed it works, but id required for the purpose. What am I missing here?

regards,/t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, bodyId seem to require regular js,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.CKEDITOR ) {
window.CKEDITOR.config.bodyId = 'thePage';
}
</script>
```

And browser-caches can be a pain..

regards,